# Intellij IDEA 14 - python Live Template with binding to class properties

Tags: python, intellij-idea, code-generation, intellij-14, live-templates

I am pretty new to Intellij Live Templates, so to the point: In Intellij IDEA 14 I can define a [Python class template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51945923), which at the end looks like this (without comments):

```
class Car(object)
    def __init__(self,)
```

And when I type arguments, they can be assigned to fields with magic `Alt + Enter` suggestion:

```
class Car(object)
    def __init__(self, engine)
        self.engine = engine
```

And then it allows me to live change variable to "private":

```
class Car(object)
    def __init__(self, engine)
        self.__engine = engine
```

But, is a way to make it automatic, for example i type `engine` and it generates `self.__engine = engine`? Thank you for all your answers - of course any useful links which will help me figure it out on my own are very welcomed.